# Show custom interstitial ad like as admob interstitial ad

Tags: android, interstitial

We are currently using admob's interstitial ad in our app. What we have in our first splash screen is:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mContext = this;

    requestNewInterstitialList();
}

private void requestNewInterstitialList() {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.gl_start_app_inter));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
                mContext.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I requested `interstitial` from `onCreate()` in our splash screen. Notice that in `interstitial` ad in `onAdLoaded()` I started `MainActivity.class` via `intent` and this will definitely start that screen without closing `interstitial` ad! So, it will just start new screen in background and show interstitial ad at a time! After that in `onAdOpened()` of ad I just finished my current activity(Splash screen) and that also that not affect the `interstitial` ad and in mean while when user close the ad in the behind main screen is loaded!

Now situation is that we have some sponsors and they want show custom built interstitial ad in our App! So, I made that in `DialogFragment`:

```
public class DF_Interstitial_Ad extends DialogFragment {
private LayoutInterstitialAdBinding mBinding;
private Context mContext;
private String adUrl;

private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private PlayerView exoPlayerView;
private long playBackPosition = 0;
private boolean isPlayerReady = false;
private boolean isOnPause = false;

private InterAdListener mAdListener = null;

public DF_Interstitial_Ad(@NonNull Context mContext, @NonNull String adUrl) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.adUrl = adUrl;

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), R.layout.layout_interstitial_ad, null,
            false);

    dataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory();
    exoPlayerView = mBinding.playerAd;
    initializePlayer();
}

private class ModelInterStitialAd {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String appIconUrl;
    private String videoUrl;
    private String installUrl;
    private float rattings;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getAppIconUrl() {
        return appIconUrl;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public String getInstallUrl() {
        return installUrl;
    }

    public float getRattings() {
        return rattings;
    }
}

//region Data source...
private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
private MediaSource mediaSource;
private AdsLoader adsLoader;

private void releaseAdsLoader() {
    if (adsLoader != null) {
        adsLoader.release();
        adsLoader = null;
        Objects.requireNonNull(exoPlayerView.getOverlayFrameLayout()).removeAllViews();
    }
}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        playBackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        player.release();
        player = null;
        mediaSource = null;
        Log.i("Player>>>", "Player released");
    }
    if (adsLoader != null) {
        releaseAdsLoader();
    }
}

private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory() {
    return MyApplication.getInstance().buildDataSourceFactory(null);
}
//endregion

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialog);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).getWindow()).addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    if (mAdListener != null) {
        mAdListener.onShow();
    }

    playPausePlayer(true);

    return mBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isOnPause = false;
    playPausePlayer(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isOnPause = true;
    playPausePlayer(true);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdListener != null) {
        mAdListener.onClose();
    }
    releasePlayer();
}

//region Player zone...
private void initializePlayer() {
    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);

    exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    exoPlayerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    exoPlayerView.setUseController(false);

    mBinding.viewMain.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isPlayerReady)
            if (player != null) {
                if (player.getPlaybackState() == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                    mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playBackPosition = 0;
                    playPausePlayer(true);
                } else {
                    if (player.getPlayWhenReady()) {
                        playPausePlayer(false);
                        mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        playPausePlayer(true);
                        mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
    });

    player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                if (!isPlayerReady) {
                    isPlayerReady = true;
                    if (mAdListener != null) {
                        mAdListener.onLoaded();
                    }
                }
                if (isOnPause)
                    playPausePlayer(false);
            }
        }
    });
        prepareExoPlayer();
    }

private void prepareExoPlayer() {
    mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(adUrl));
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(VideoCache.getInstance(mContext),
            dataSourceFactory);
    @C.ContentType int type = Util.inferContentType(uri, null);
    switch (type) {
        case C.TYPE_HLS:
            return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).setAllowChunklessPreparation(true).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_OTHER:
            return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_DASH:
        case C.TYPE_SS:
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
    }
}

private void playPausePlayer(boolean play) {
    if (player != null) {
        if (play) {
            player.seekTo(playBackPosition);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            player.getPlaybackState();
            mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            playBackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            player.getPlaybackState();
            mBinding.ivPlayVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
//endregion

public void setmAdListener(InterAdListener mAdListener) {
    this.mAdListener = mAdListener;
}

public boolean isLoaded() {
    return isPlayerReady;
}
}
```

This is my `DialogFragment` in which I implemented my own custom interstitial ad. So, after that I just request it regularly same as admob's `interstitial` ad from splash screen like:

```
private void requestMyInterstitialAd() {
    DF_Interstitial_Ad dfInterstitialAd = new DF_Interstitial_Ad(mContext, "https://booads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/output.mp4");
    dfInterstitialAd.setmAdListener(new InterAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoaded() {
            super.onLoaded();
            if (dfInterstitialAd != null && dfInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                dfInterstitialAd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SplashScreen");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            super.onShow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose() {
            super.onClose();

        }
    });
}
```

It is show next screen(MainActivity) in front of screen rather than `DialogFragment` of ad! So, what to do? for showing ad in front of user and in mean while open next activity behind the ad! I already tried showing ad in `activity` rather than `DialogFragment` but its also not working for me!